# MVC4 REST API always returns response in JSON format

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I used MVC4 Rest APi for my latest project. But I ran into one issue which I'm unable to figure out.

My request supports both JSON and XML format and I have no problem in getting a response from my request.

While testing I found out issue that while hitting this API using ["Advanced Rest Client"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US), even if I send request in JSON format, the response is always in XML format.

But if I use Fiddler, it works fine i.e JSON request gives JSON response and XML request gives XML response

```
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/xml 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


Response headers 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Pragma: no-cache 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Expires: -1 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 
Date: Mon, 21 Jul 2014 12:01:27 GMT 
Content-Length: 340
```

I'm afraid the end users might face the same issue. So is there any way to fix this?

All I can find is to forcefully use only one format for my Web API to solve this. But I have to support both formats.

Is there a way to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header of a request **does not** dictate the type of response from the server, it's used to determine the *request* type.

The Web API uses [content negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) to determine the media type of the response, specifically the `Accept` header. To ensure an XML response you will need to set the `Accept` header like

```
Accept: application/xml;
```

Comment: Yes, I read about that but ideally I want to respond a JSON request with JSON response and a XML request with an XML response. I don't want to force a XML response even to a JSOn request. Is it possible?

Comment: @hellrokr the response type can be determined by other factors of the request i.e. if you omit the `Accept` header and provide an XML body it should respond with XML (same with JSON).

Comment: Accepting this as answer but this does not work. I had to use Accept: application/xml. Adding "*/*", again returns the response in JSON. You can try it out in your browser.

Comment: @hellrokr `*/*` must take priority if that's the case (although I would have thought order dictated that). Regardless, that was an example, the answer was more about using the `Accept` header (i've updated the answer anyway).